# CSS files from LESS files are not created when using WebPack

Tags: webpack

I have 2 LESS files:

```
**styles/consts.less**

    @gray: #202020;

**styles/main.less**

    @import 'consts.less';

    body { background-color: @gray; }
```

I tried to compile, minify and bundle the 2 less files using Webpack:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.min.css',
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },

  entry: {
    'scripts.min': './scripts/scripts.js',
  },  

  output: {
    path:  __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({}),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),      
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: false
      })
    ]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
      }
    ]
  }

};
```

I would like the resulting file, `styles.min.css`, to be placed on `dist` folder.

The javascript file `scripts.min.js` is successufuly created ...

However the CSS file `styles.min.css` from the LESS files is not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported the less files into your js files? If yes, can you try removing the first 2 lines in minimizer?

Comment: I missed the importing. My fault. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to import the less files into your js files?